# Unlocking scale with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm making a script that uses `canvas.zoomScale(550_000, False)` zoom.

However, if the user is zoom-locked, the script will run incorrectly, but it will not give any error.

[image]

Is it possible to somehow unlock the scale lock using PyQGIS or at least inform the user that the scale is locked and abort the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the scale is locked with

```
iface.mapCanvas().scaleLocked()
```

and change the state of it with

```
iface.mapCanvas().setScaleLocked(False)
```

as described in the QgsMapCanvas documentation.
https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html